# gsutil rsync syncing to remote server?

Tags: rsync, gsutil

Is it possible to use gsutil's rsync command to target a remote server?

I want to do:

```
gsutil -m rsync -d -r gs://some-bucket username@some.remote.server.net:destination
```

If not, what would you recommend?